# Jcarousel lite not showing up on page load in safari and chrome

Tags: safari, google-chrome, jcarousel

I have this plug-in in use on my home page which is running on WAMP. It works great in every browser except Safari and Google Chrome. In those browsers the carousel doesn’t show up when I first load the page, nor when I hit reload. When I navigate to the home page via the on page navigation link then it shows up.

Any ideas what could be causing this?

Thanks,
Jeremy

Answer (score 6):

Had this problem too, found that by giving the pictures i was displaying a width="nn px" and height="nn px" solved my problem ;)

Answer (score 5):

Try putting your gallery initialization in the window load function,
something like so:

```
$(window).load(function() {

    $(".gallery").jCarouselLite({
        btnNext: ".next",
        btnPrev: ".prev",
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the similar issue. Make sure you are giving width and height to your images. 
For some reason google chrome and safari are not fetching/calculating the height/width automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to what user703735 said above. I found by forcing a height and width of my scrolling images it would bypass jcarousel trying to calculate them. I also found it caused a few issues with IE8 without values so this may help someone else with the same issue.

```
<li style="width: XXpx; height: XXpx;"> ... image here ... </li>
```

Where XX is the size in pixels.